# How to run flask python website permanently?

Tags: python, deployment, flask, hosting

I'm following [Flask Quickstart guide](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/) and can run my web app via http://myip.com:5000.

One issue is that my web is only accessible as long as I keep my SSH remote connection session - when I sleep/shutdown my PC, the website shutdown too.

How can I make it permanent available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a regular web server, such as apache2. You can't use the python server for production purposes. Here is how you do it with apache: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/

Comment: May you brief steps to get the wap run under Apache? Great thanks!

Comment: The link I posted describes how to configure Apache to run flask apps quite well (those are the instructions I followed myself). If you don't know how to install apache, just run `sudo apt-get install apache2` if you're using ubuntu. If you need more help than that, I suggest googling it and learning more about apache.

Comment: Got tht @Brian Keller-Heikkila.

Comment: Do you have an up-to-date link for these docs?